# Switch between admin account and "me"

Tags: interaction-design, information-architecture

I am working on a design for a platform where there are users, and some of them are "managers" so they are able to view data about the team they manage.

The home page shows a dashboard with cards for those items that need an action to be performed.
As a user, they can only see their cards.
As a manager, they can see their own cards, AND they can switch to their "Manager" account to see their team's data too.

---

The design I have inherited has a dropdown selector on the top-right of the screen where the users can choose "me" or "team" view.
Some of the feedback I received (namely the PM and the Lead Eng, whereas I am the new Designer) would prefer a toggle switch between the two options.

example:

```
me [toggle      ] team
me [      toggle] team
```

It just doesn't feel right, and I can't figure out what's wrong with it.
Please, send help!

Comment: Why can't managers see their personal cards and team data at the same time? Is there really a requirement for two different views for managers and if yes, where does this requirement come from? Is it based on user research?

Comment: @locationunknown Quite right.  One wonders if this is an implementation limitation (the query is parametrized and made just once per page load...) incumbent on the developer to fix once the designer makes this need clear.

Comment: I like the idea of showing all the information at once, without the need to switch to a different role. So, the problem wasn't what UI control should be used to change role, rather, the problem is that we might not need to switch role at all!

Comment: If it's dangerous to stay in admin mode as opposed to me mode, you can for example style some elements (like title bar or FAB) in red so the user won't forget they remained in admin mode.

Answer (score 1):

If the experience can't be merged into a single one and have items differentiated between team member and manager then usually the approach is to have a button / knob somewhere visible where the user can make the switch between the roles. If the platform logs out frequently this option can also be presented on login.

Take this with a grain of salt as understanding the jobs to be done by the user is vital to craft a good UX in your project.

Answer (score 0):

If the user doesn't have to perform interactions with the data tiles, I think it would be quite smart to display all data at once and not switch. However, if the user has to edit things, it would be better to separate those users clearly, to avoid accidental editing of wrong items.
You could either switch the whole user, or show the team's statistics, maybe on a background that is differently coloured.